# Calculating percentage, using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I would like to calculate sum of the `bid_amount` column and percentage value of the sum outputted from the table. Am only getting bid amount for one row which is 78. Not the sum of the bid_amount as i would like it.

**bal table on phpmyadmin**

[image]

**My controller**

```
$data['accountbalance']=$this->Agentaccount_model->accountbalance();
```

**My Model**

```
public function accountbalance()  {  
    $area = $this->session->userdata('area');
    $this->db->select('*,SUM(bal.bid_amount)AS Total');
    $this->db->from('bal');
    $this->db->where('bal.area' , $area);
    $this->db->join('agent','bal.area=agent.area');
    $this->db->where('agent.status',1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;  
}
```

**My View**

```
   <?php $total_sum=0;  ?>
   <?php $row_count = 0; ?>
   <?php
   foreach ($accountbalance->result() as $row)  
   {
   ?>      
   <address>
    <?php   
     echo 'Account Balance ' . $row->bid_amount;
     $total_sum += $row->bid_amount;
     $row_count++;
     ?>  
    </address>               
   <?php echo 'Sum ' . $total_sum*$row_count; ?>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: So this is not _Rocket Science_ What have you tried SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Hey. I have made edits and included what i tried before. Please help.

Comment: You have not even shown the syntax error message.

Comment: Have included it now

Comment: It soes not help readability and therefore debuggability to have all those unnecessary PHP start and stop tags all over the place `<?php ...?><?php ...?>`

Comment: I use postgres and not my sql but shouldnt it be `SUM(bal.bid_amount) AS Total`

Comment: I think AS Total needs to be outside the brackets. And seriously dont open and close php tags over and over again. even if you have to use this syntax `<?php if(condition): ?> <?php endif;?>` It atleast becomes more readable

Comment: Also Initialise `$total_sum=0` outside the loop

Comment: Fix your query as @Jose said. This will fix your MySQL error but most likely you have other errors

Comment: Thank you. had removed some html between those opening and closing tags for the sake of posting to this group.

Comment: SUM(bal.bid_amount) AS Total  worked Jose but now am not able to get the total of the columns, am only able to get the value for one row. Made the edits above to define my new problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like what you want to do, without all the PHP start stop tags it is easier to read and initializing the `$total_sum=0;` outside the loop. Also you will need a count of the rows processed to get a proper percentage so I added that.

```
<?php
    // initialization moved outside the loop
    $total_sum=0;
    $row_count = 0;

    foreach ($accountbalance->result() as $row) {
        echo 'Account Balance ' . $row->bid_amount;
        $total_sum += $row->bid_amount;
        $row_count++;
    }
    echo 'Average ' . $total_sum / $row_count;
```

Comment: Am not able to get the total of the column, am only able to get the value for one row. Made the edits above to define my new problem.